# Django LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to running the appserver with python manage.py runserver with python 3.8.2 and django 3.0.3. I've setup a mysql database connection and inserted my "myApp.apps.myAppConfig" into INSTALLED_APPS, declared a couple of database-view based models, a form and a view. Nothing that seems too out of the way for the tutorials i've found. When i run the python manage.py runserver command, this is the output:

> Watching for file changes with StatReloader Performing system
>   checks...
>
> Exception in thread django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py",
>   line 155, in get_app_config
>       return self.app_configs[app_label] KeyError: 'admin'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py",
>   line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()   File "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py",
>   line 870, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py",
>   line 53, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
>   line 117, in inner_run
>       self.check(display_num_errors=True)   File "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 392, in check
>       all_issues = self._run_checks(   File "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 382, in _run_checks
>       return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py",
>   line 72, in run_checks
>       new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
>   line 13, in check_url_config
>       return check_resolver(resolver)   File "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
>   line 23, in check_resolver
>       return check_method()   File "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 407, in check
>       for pattern in self.url_patterns:   File "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
>   line 48, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 588, in url_patterns
>       patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File
>   "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
>   line 48, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 581, in urlconf_module
>       return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 127, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 991, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 783, in
>   exec_module   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\celli\Desktop\Interventi Comuni\Python\django-projects\zabbixPyFace\zabbixPyFace\urls.py", line
>   21, in 
>       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),   File "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
>   line 224, in inner
>       self._setup()   File "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py",
>   line 537, in _setup
>       AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config('admin').default_site)   File
>   "C:\Users\celli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py",
>   line 162, in get_app_config
>       raise LookupError(message) LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.

I tried searching big G for answers but there's many sources that can cause this problem, could any of you gurus provide some insight?

Update:

I've already checked the INSTALLED_APPS and django.contrib.admin is present:

INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', # jupyter notebook plugin 'django_extensions', ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question, searching the net for informations regarding this error leads to many ambigous results, since this error seems to be fired even if the root cause was of another nature. In my case i forgot to apply the `python manage.py makemigrations` directive.

Comment: did you mean `makemigrations` directive ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add "django.contrib.admin" to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.

Comment: Thanks justin for your prompt response, but i've already checked the INSTALLED_APPS and it's present:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # jupyter notebook plugin
    'django_extensions',
]

Answer (score 2):

I had to face the same situation, was running it in a virtual environment so there was no case of any package dependencies error. I tried to debug it in all possible ways, like checking my 'settings.py' file, 'urls.py' & many more but wasn't successful.
So a day full of debugging & troubleshooting, I was about to restart my project & then I came to 'models.py' & there was this error:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
image = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.content

def serialize(self):
    return {
        "id" : self.id,
        "content" : self.content #missin comma
        "likes" : random.randint(0,400),
    }
```

See I just forgot to comma here & it didn't show me the exact syntax error, instead it showed me some other that wasn't even related to it

**PS : Check out for any syntax error in the 'models.py' or other file if you're using one.**

Comment: Well the error is mentioned in the question above,you can look there- it's Django Lookup Error.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this error when adding new cross-app dependencies involving three apps in my own Django project: A, B, and C. Originally, app C used a model from app B in one of its migrations, but did not have an explicit migration dependency in the migration file.

Then I changed a model in app A to depend on a model in app C. So A depended on C, which depended on B. Django didn't know that C depended on B, which led to this error.

Adding the latest migration from B as a dependency in C resolved the problem, e.g.:

```
dependencies = [
  ("B", "0001_make_B_models"),
]
```